# GitHub Pages deployment no longer works

Tags: github-pages, create-react-app

Currently have a Create-React-App project that was successfully deployed on Github Pages. After a few minutes, I refreshed the page and it no longer rendered. I didn't make any changes. Here are the console errors that appear. As well as a link to the repo as well.

[photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkaJs.png)
[photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0go0B.png)

https://github.com/anthonyhem/page

Answer (score 0):

resolved.

Had to change homepage data in the package json to point to the custom domain name.